# Alfresco 4.0 Community - document preview for cyrillic utf8(?) txt, html shows malformed text

Tags: utf-8, alfresco, preview, malformed, cyrillic

Alfresco 4.0 Community previewer displays utf8(?) txt and html documents with cyrillic malformed. How to enable utf8 for previewer or at least force it show normally russian and english text?

Txt previewing - it has most strange behaviour and maybe here not only one problem, creating or editing this text document:

- тестовый текст - test text
- 日本人テストテキスト - japanese test text
- español - spanish

[image]

Previewer shows it malformed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/96n6j.jpg

**When downloading document it normally displaying in Notepad++, it says, that it  has ANSI as UTF-8 encoding (UTF-8 without BOM)**

**When inline editing document again - all fields shows normal at inline editing form, but previewer still shows mallformed text.**

Html previewing, pay attention, that preview encoding looks different than in preview for text creating/inline editing case:
_http://i.imgur.com/BPtvC3Z.jpg

POST from chrome developers tools for HTML previewing:

```
Request URL:...:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/type/cm%3acontent/formprocessor
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:388
Content-Type:application/json
....
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
X-Requested-With:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
...
prop_app_editInline: "true"
prop_cm_content: "<p>Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð²Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑÑ‚ - test text</p>↵<p>æ—¥æœ¬äººãƒ†ã‚¹ãƒˆãƒ†ã‚­ã‚¹ãƒˆ - japanese test text</p>↵<p>espa&ntilde;ol - spanish</p>"
prop_cm_description: "html test"
prop_cm_name: "html test"
prop_cm_title: "html test"
prop_mimetype: "text/html"
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:166
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 13 May 2013 23:10:36 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

For part "Ñ‚ÐµÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð²Ñ‹Ð¹ Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑÑ" decoder says, that when he converting CP1252 → UTF-8 he get "те�товый тек��" - pretty close to "тестовый текст".

alfresco 4.0.e on ubuntu linux server 13.04
alfresco-community-4.0.e-installer-linux-x64.bin

In rare cases when creating very simple text (or maybe it just moon phases influence ;-) ), for example if it written only one russian word "текст" - previewer displays it normally at FIRST time, and only when creating first document in repository, but on reload previewer or edit, creating next document with same text "текст" - it malformed again.

Comment: Can you use the node browser to check what encoding Alfresco thinks the content is, both when it's showing correctly and not?

Comment: Is this happening only in the previewer? Have you tried to set a document Title (not name) or create a tag with some of those characters and see if they display ok? Just wanted to know.

Comment: Hi, it's never shows preview correctly :-(
Only in strange rare cases, which I can't catch.
Here is data from node browser:
their parent:
http://i.imgur.com/ADQ9cbf.jpg
TEXT content:
http://i.imgur.com/URWbkig.jpg
cm:content:
http://i.imgur.com/L92GB7z.jpg
cm:webpreview:
http://i.imgur.com/tPfZYi0.jpg
cm:content of cm:webpreview:
http://i.imgur.com/ktQiHWu.jpg

HTML content:
http://i.imgur.com/ethIGwt.jpg
cm:content:
http://i.imgur.com/Yx5SVDT.jpg
webpreview:
http://i.imgur.com/BQESo4R.jpg
cm:content of webpreview:
http://i.imgur.com/JkAlNkZ.jpg
Also - titles, desc, tags - all OK.

Comment: so, it shows encoding UTF8, locale - ru, for everything with russian letters (or if russian letters only in content), even displays content itself correctly, but webpreview content still mallformed.